# How does one create an assembly for a tlbimp-ed COM DLL in SQLServer?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, dll, vb6, sqlclr

Context: SSMS 2012, SQL Server 2005, C#, an ActiveX JSON DLL written in VB6

I'm trying to use a JSON parsing COM DLL in a CLR stored procedure. I've run the DLL through TlbImp, viz

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\TlbImp.exe" BOJasonLite.dll /out:NETBOJasonLite.dll
```

but when I try, in SSMS, to create an assembly from it, I get the following:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY failed because method 'parse' on type 'NETBOJasonLite._JSON'  in safe assembly 'NETBOJasonLite' has invalid attribute 0x1003. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 6215)
```

Any idea what this means?

Comment: What parameters did you use with `TlbImp`?

Comment: Have you seen this [question on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bc45f3f4-8cdc-4b5a-82a4-f653e668c8c3/error-while-registering-assembly-that-uses-activex-wrapper-stdole?forum=sqlnetfx)? It's fairly old, but may still have some value to it.

Comment: @boost I'm interested in this issue - did scheien's suggestion work?